# How do see fluids through glass (Eevee)?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, fluid-simulation, glass

I don't see my fluid inside the glass, but i can see the object inside the glass. Does somebody know, what i have to change, to see fluids through glass?

Or is this not possible in Eevee? Can i fake it somehow?[image]

Comment: Hi there : ) .Can you add an image showing the node setup of both the glass and water material . It's always important when it comes to questions regarding shading. Its leterally impossible to know whats happening without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the *Glass* node you need to enable the following options :

- *Render panel > Screen Space Reflection*
- *Material panel > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend*
- *Material panel > Settings > Screen Space Refraction*

There is a limitation for the moment in *Eevee*: You can't see an object that is in *Blende Mode > Alpha Blend* through an object that has a *Glass* material, as you can see here, object 2 is not visible:

[image]

If you give object 1 a bit of transparency and therefore decrease its *Glass* value, you kind of get around the problem (you can also get rid of the *Glass* node and find another way to simulate glass, like a mix bewteen *Glossy* and *Transparent*):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This helps. I didn't activate the Alpha Blend for the Fluid. Now with alpha blend everything is fine.