# Texture not visible behind glass in Eevee?

Tags: texturing, eevee-render-engine, glass

Textures don't show up behind glass in Eevee, I can see the object but it's missing the textures. I guess it should work so I must do something wrong...

An example:
[image]

Comment: This is general setup https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/189727/2214 just missing texture but object visible is weird, can you attach screen to your Q or material node tree? Or simplified blend file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Worth reading: [15 limitations of real time rendering](https://cgcookie.com/articles/blender-cycles-vs-eevee-15-limitations-of-real-time-rendering)

Comment: I'm aware of these limitations, mostly, but this issue is not listed. And I'm pretty sure I saw textures behind refractive materials in video games before...

Comment: I figured it out - I edited my answer to reflect the changes. Notice that in the new graph I used, I mixed a Glass BSDF with the Glossy instead of a Diffuse like in my first example.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - Solved

You had the blend mode on the textured cube set to Alpha Blend, this stopped the refraction. You still need to use Alpha Blend on the Transparent cube however, as well as using more than a plain Glass BSDF node.

Alpha Blend:
[image: RefractBad]

Opaque:
[image: Refract]

Comment: Thanks! I can see the textures but there is no refraction...

Comment: Great, that was it, thank you!

Comment: Why just don't change Texture Cube to Alpha Opaque? Simple Glass works for me ...