# simulated cloth doesnt show through glass in Evee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, cloth-simulation, glass

### What I did

I made like this desk with mat by using cloth simulation
[image]

### Problem

When I use cycles, looks like that through glass
[image]

And Evee looks like that. Desk mat doesnt show, and I realized under tap is not shown as well just now(it's image texture).
[image]

This is glass shader
[image]
Somebody knows how fix it??

## *add 1

I changed material settings of desk mat like this pic ↓
[image]

and result is like that, as you can see desk mat appears!
(I still doubt its proper setting cuz according to your sources which pasted, alpha blend is proper setting)
so I changed material settings of place under tap as well, the same as desk mat.
but unfortunately it shows only frame.[image]

Comment: Is there any transparency or transmission in the cloth materials? Transmission/glass doesn't layer in eevee, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193443/texture-not-visible-behind-glass-in-eevee. If its not transmission but alpha transparency, you need to set the appropriate blend modes on both materials. Also useful is https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189716/how-do-see-fluids-through-glass-eevee/189727#189727

Comment: thanks for answering :)  I added "*add1". tried to change material settings.  desk mat appears, but place under tap still hides(image texture)

Comment: check all the visibility settings on the bit under the tap? Opaque for blend mode is the correct setting for non-transparent objects, and either alpha blend or alpha hash are generally the way to go for transparent objects, more info: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/materials/settings.html

Comment: omg, I realized under tip place has two materials, and I forgot fixing one of them. Now I set "oppaque" and everything appears through glass in Evee.     thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change material settings
blend mode: opaque
shadow mode: opaque
screen space refraction: no