# See-througn Glass - problems viewing a color sphere inside a see-through glass cylinder

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing

Hope someone could help.

I have (intendedly) a color sphere inside a see-through glass cylinder (Please see attached). When I use the "solid mode" in "viewport shading," (the left top window) I could partially see the sphere. But in "rendered mode" I do not. Any suggestions regarding what I am missing regarding the set up of the see-through glass material would be appreciated.

Attached please also find my settings. Many thanks in advance

[image: "solid" VS "rendered"]

[image: Setting 1]

[image: Setting 2]

[image: Setting 3]

[image: Setting 4]

Comment: in Eevee you need to enable some options to make the glass work if this is your question

Comment: @moonboot Really? You successfully duplicated your self ... probably this one should be linked to this Q https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/162935/2214

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos ... Could you change dupli to above link? ...  Older and more descriptive. Thank you

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189716/how-do-see-fluids-through-glass-eevee

Answer (score 1):

In Eevee for your material you need to choose another *Blend Mode* than *Opaque*, and enable *Screen Space Refraction*:

[image]

And in the Render panel enable *Screen Space Reflections* and *Refraction*:

[image]